# tensorflow Layer weight initialization with seed produces the same values in different layers as well

Tags: tensorflow

I am defining a new layer with two weights initialized in different shapes:

class SimpleDense(tensorflow.keras.layers.Layer):

```
def __init__(self):
    super(SimpleDense, self).__init__()

def build(self):
    self.w1 = self.add_weight(shape=(5, 5),
                           initializer=tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(seed=1234),
                           trainable=True)
    self.w2 = self.add_weight(shape=(5,6),
                           initializer=tf.keras.initializers.truncated_normal(seed=1234),
                           trainable=True)
def call(self):
    pass
```

The weights w1 and w2 share the same first 25 floats. So it seems like the same vector of floats is used everywhere. Additionally, separate instances of the same layer class also share the same weights.

```
sd1 = SimpleDense()
sd1.build()

sd2 = SimpleDense()
sd2.build()

sd1.w1
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(5, 5) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.00682165,  0.03804878, -0.08698365,  0.02000416, -0.0379169 ],
   [-0.04041002,  0.00349349, -0.04125977, -0.04460358,  0.06052992],
   [ 0.09549459,  0.06161878, -0.02399441,  0.07976086,  0.05028958],
   [-0.00204308, -0.09973445, -0.07213714,  0.0325163 , -0.09121864],
   [-0.07422495, -0.04935479, -0.03293147,  0.01593254,  0.03643443]],
  dtype=float32)>

sd1.w2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(5, 6) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.00682165,  0.03804878, -0.08698365,  0.02000416, -0.0379169 ,
    -0.04041002],
   [ 0.00349349, -0.04125977, -0.04460358,  0.06052992,  0.09549459,
     0.06161878],
   [-0.02399441,  0.07976086,  0.05028958, -0.00204308, -0.09973445,
    -0.07213714],
   [ 0.0325163 , -0.09121864, -0.07422495, -0.04935479, -0.03293147,
     0.01593254],
   [ 0.03643443,  0.04764059,  0.00034371, -0.0784961 , -0.01348116,
    -0.05637978]], dtype=float32)>

sd2.w2
<tf.Variable 'Variable:0' shape=(5, 6) dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-0.00682165,  0.03804878, -0.08698365,  0.02000416, -0.0379169 ,
    -0.04041002],
   [ 0.00349349, -0.04125977, -0.04460358,  0.06052992,  0.09549459,
     0.06161878],
   [-0.02399441,  0.07976086,  0.05028958, -0.00204308, -0.09973445,
    -0.07213714],
   [ 0.0325163 , -0.09121864, -0.07422495, -0.04935479, -0.03293147,
     0.01593254],
   [ 0.03643443,  0.04764059,  0.00034371, -0.0784961 , -0.01348116,
    -0.05637978]], dtype=float32)>
```

I was expecting different behavior especially with different layer instances.

Comment: That's what setting a seed does - it produces the same sets of values every time.

Comment: That's right. It is mentioned that "Note that a seeded initializer will produce the same random values across multiple calls." in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/TruncatedNormal

Comment: It actually depends on the version of TensorFlow if you are using 2.9 or earlier you will get differents values but in the latests versions you actually have the same value in eager execution

Comment: In v2.9 documentation, it is mentioned that "Note that a seeded initializer will not produce the same random values across multiple calls, but multiple initializers will produce the same sequence when constructed with the same seed value." https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.9/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/TruncatedNormal

Answer (score 1):

It is mentioned that "Note that a seeded initializer will produce the same random values across multiple calls." in https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/initializers/TruncatedNormal